# What to do about "Verification inconclusive" errors

Tags: dafny

I have a method that results in an error "verificaton inconclusive".  It's not clear why the verification is inconclusive.  It doesn't seem to be a time out and there is no indication of what verification conditions can't be proved.  In short: what does this mean?

I'm using version 2.0.0.  I don't recall seeing this message in version 1.9.7.

The particular method where I have the problem is.

```
function c( n : int, r : int ) : int
    requires 0 <= r <= n
{
    if( r==0 ) then 1
    else if( r==n ) then 1
    else c(n-1, r-1) + c( n-1, r )
}

method combinations1Row( m : array2<int>, i : int )
    requires m != null
    requires m.Length0 == m.Length1 
    requires var N := m.Length0 ; 0 <= i < N ;
    requires forall n,r : int :: 0 <= r <= n < i ==> m[n,r] == c(n,r)
    modifies m
    ensures forall n,r : int :: 0 <= r <= n <= i ==> m[n,r] == c(n,r)
{
    var N := m.Length0 ;
    var j := 0 ;
    while( j <= i )
        invariant 0 <= j <= i+1
        invariant forall n,r : int :: 0 <= r <= n < i ==> m[n,r] == c(n,r)
        invariant forall r : int :: 0 <= r < j ==> m[i,r] == c(i,r)
    {
        if( j==0 ) { m[i,j] := 1 ; }
        else if( j==i ) { m[i,j] := 1 ; }
        else { m[i,j] := m[i-1,j-1] + m[i-1,j] ; }
        assert m[i,j] == c(i,j) ;
        assert forall r : int :: 0 <= r <= j ==> m[i,r] == c(i,r) ;
        j := j+1 ;
    }
    assert j==i+1 ;
}
```

Comment: "Inconclusive" usually indicates a bug in the tools somewhere. This code verifies for me on my machine and on rise4fun. Can you try to reproduce this on the command line? If you can reproduce it, please open a bug report on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny). If possible also include the Boogie output generated by passing the `/print:log.bpl` option.

Comment: Thanks.  It verifies consistently from the command line.  It seems also to verify sometimes in VS and sometimes give the "inconclusive" error.